# How to get GUI to update while program is running?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface

I am trying to get the GUI to update after each iteration of the loop. I have read other answers to similar questions and still can't get it to work. In the code below I call simulate which runs through the loop calling step which calculates and changes GUI components as needed but the GUI isn't updating until after the loop completely ends. How can I get it to update after each iteration?

```
public void step(View v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
        update(i);

    count++;

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), count + "", 1000).show();
}

public void simulate(View v) {
    while (!pause) {
        step(v);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void update(final int i)
{
            //This goes through each button and counts the neighbors (this is the 
            //intensive work
    int neighbors = getNeighbors(i);

            //With the information provided from the getNeighbors the following if
            //statement updates the GUI using the dead and alive method calls.
    if (isAlive(cells[i])) {
        if (neighbors < 2)
            dead(cells[i]);
        else if (neighbors > 3)
            dead(cells[i]);
    } 
    else {
        if (neighbors == 3)
            alive(cells[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Get in the habit of always throwing some braces around that `for loop`.  Not saying that is or isn't your problem, just that it takes 0 effort and could potentially save your from unbelievable head-aches in the future =)

Comment: The update method just tells the buttons to change colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are always adviced that , **UI work should be on the UI-Thread, and Non-UI work on Non-UI Thread, but from HoneyComb android version it became a LAW**. `When we start an` `application in Android, it start on the Dedicated UI thread, creating any other thread` `will drop you off the UI thread, you normally do this to do some process intensive work,` `but when you want to display the output of the non-ui thread process, on the ui thread` `then you will experience lagging, exception etc...`

From my view this can be done in `two` ways....

1. Using **Handler**... `Handler stores the reference of the thread on which it was` `created, Initialize Handler inside the` **onCreate()** `method, and then use` **handler.post()** `to update the UI thread.`
2. Use **AsyncTask<>** provided by android, it synchronizes the UI and Non-UI threads

   Methods in AsyncTask<>

   `doInBackground(String...) // Work on the Non-UI thread`

   `postExecute(String result) // Getting the Output from the Non-Ui thread and`

   `Putting the Output back on the UI Thread`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are running that code in the main thread of your application. The GUI runs on the same thread and can not be updated while you are blocking it.

You have to do the calculations in a different task and then send a message to the main process to update the GUI.
Read this for background-information (if you are new to this, you have read the backgrounds first):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html

The easiest way to do this is to use AsyncTask and then do the GUI update with "onProgressUpdate()".
Although AsyncTask already makes things pretty easy, you have to mind that the underlying activity can be destroyed while AsyncTask is running. This is not really well covered in the documentation but I find that the use of Fragments is probably the best way of dealing with it. Read this article for a quite nice description:

http://blogactivity.wordpress.com/2011/09/01/proper-use-of-asynctask/

Remark: read also the AsyncTask documentation. I could not post the link due to restrictions of the forum.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use AsyncTask for this.

Try to read the documentation..

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html